# Why is my folder in "Restricted Mode" when I clicked on "I don't trust the authors"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code, opened a folder, and there was a popup saying:

[image: popup]

After clicking "I don't trust the author", the folder opens like this
and it happens with the every folder I open:

[image: untrusted]

Can anybody tell me why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable workspace trust in VS Code 1.57?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914899/how-can-i-disable-workspace-trust-in-vs-code-1-57)

Comment: The "our docs" link on that popup should have led you to this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust